# Objects with two properties only

Tags: oop

I am trying to decide on the best approach to the following problem:

I have a class called Desk. A desk has lots of properties. A Desk may have some objects on it. The current application specifies that it can have Pencils, Computers, or Cups on the desk. A few more objects may be added in the future. It can have one or none of each object. The Pencils have a property of Color, all of the objects have an ID and name. All of this information must be persistent so is stored in a database in some form.

Do I:

```
public class Desk {
    public int property1;
    public int property2;
    ...
    public ISet<DeskObject> deskObjects;
}

public DeskObject {
    public int deskObjectID;
    public String name;

    public DeskObject(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

public Computer extends DeskObject {
    DeskObject("Computer");
}
public Pencil extends DeskObject {
    DeskObject("Pencil);
    public Color color;
}
```

I also need to easily tell which objects a Desk contains in O(1) time. This means I will have to override hashcode and equals (probably by just returning the ID) for the DeskObjects so I can do set.contains(object). It seems like overkill and a misuse of objects. Surely there is a better solution?

Comment: If I understand your Q, overriding `Equals` and in turn `Hashcode` is used when you need to compare 2 objects, do you?

Comment: Ahh yeah, just so I can tell if the Desk does or does not have a Pencil, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your domain is about desks and the objects they contain, then an object model like this is entirely warranted. The only question you need to ask yourself is this: **Is this my domain model, or is it a computation model?**

From the phrasing of your question, I would infer its rather the latter. Your objects do not contain any behavior (such as Desk.CleanNonRecentlyUsed()).

A domain model contains data and behavior (a true object model, I call this domain model), a computation model is data and separated behavior (procedural code).

If all your model needs to do is provide efficient lookups, you can chose any abstract representation that suits you. A lightweight object that captures just data is ok, but you could also use tuples (or to be .net specific since you mentioned GetHashCode: Annonymous classes) or just a Hashtable for the desk. Your computation model can be anything from an Index in your database (sounds reasonable in your example), a special object model, or dedicated algorithms over plain arrays.

Most of the time, it is not warranted to create a computation model when you already have a domain model. But sometimes it is.

Comment: No they do not contain any behaviour, but that is because it is a web application using an MVC approach and an ORM. Not too many of the objects contain methods :) DeskObjects are a part of the model layer, but they are very weak and simple objects.

Comment: I would not feel bad about this. It looks like a very reasonable requirement. You wont need to override equals/gethashcode if your ORM maps the pencil you try to find to the same object as the one the desk has dehydrated.